# Помогите понять запись

Tags: typescript

Новичок в TypeScript. Читаю книгу Pro Angular, не могу понять запись:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[property: string]: SimpleChange }) {...}
```

В частности, функция принимает аргумент changes, тип которого анонимный объект. Внутри этого объекта сидит анонимный массив с элементом property типа string. А что такое SimpleChange? Или я все напутал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, это не анонимный массив, это способ типизации значений неизвестных ключей объекта ([часть спецификации index types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-string-index-signatures)). Запись

```
{
  name: string,
  [key: <type A>]: <type B>
}
```

говорит о том, что в данном объекте точно будет property name с типом string, а все остальные ключи с типом `<type A>` будут содержать в себе значения с типом `<type B>`. Название ключа (key и property) не несет никакой нагрузки и может быть произвольным.

Конкретно в вашем примере передается объект, в котором есть произвольное количество ключей string, каждый из которых соответствует значению типа SimpleChange.